# bind focus to a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working in chrome 12, my code is below.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" class="tooltip" title="test1" name="group" value="1"> 1<br>        
<input type="radio" class="tooltip" title="test2" name="group" value="2"> 2<br>
<input type="radio" class="tooltip" title="test3" name="group" value="3" checked> 3<br>
<input type="text" class="tooltip" value="4" title="test4"><br>
<div class="result"> THIS SHOULD UPDATE WHEN YOU FOCUS ON ONE OF THE INPUTS </div>
```

​
JavaScript:

```
$('.tooltip').bind('focus', function(ev) {
 $('.result').html( this.value );
});
```

([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9erh/3/))

Is it possible to bind a focus event to a radio button? Can you offer an alternative?

Comment: Why not? Your code seems to be working fine.

Comment: what browser are you in? Won't work for me in chrome / firefox.

Comment: both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: that's really odd. I'm on OSX lion.

Comment: It works for me on Mac too: Select the first option and then press tab. You'll see a difference in the outline, so *now* the radio button is focused. It seems it does not get focused by just clicking on it for whatever reasons. So the question is, what do you need this for? I could imagine `change` event is sufficient to listen to.

Comment: @Finnnn my fix works for your new edit as well, did you see it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working only when you click a button if you set focus via keyboard your original code works in all browsers.

Looks like only IE will trigger the *focus* event when the button is clicked, Chrome triggers only the *click* event. Note that if you click one then press <kbd>TAB</kbd> it does work, even in Chrome.

Maybe a bug and maybe by design, anyway just handle both:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var _currentExecuting = false;
    $(".tooltip").bind("focus click", function() {
        if (!_currentExecuting) { 
            var oResult = $(".result");
            oResult.html(oResult.html() + "yoy oi " + this.value + "<br />"); 
            _currentExecuting = true;
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                _currentExecuting = false;
            }, 100);
        }
    });
});
```

Since IE browsers will trigger both the focus and click events when clicked, I had to set global flag then check for this flag before executing any code and auto clear it after some short interval.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9erh/4/).

Comment: Carefull with that. Binding to `focus` as well as `click` will execute the event twice when clicking a radio button. Add a `console.log('I have executed');` below the `$('.result')....` and you can see it being executed twice when clicking on the radio buttons in Firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/fkYfK/1/

Comment: @FrançoisWahl good point. If it's crucial, it can be fixed by some flag being set in the handler and auto cleared in a timer after a milisecond or so. If the flag is set, don't execute the code again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This seems like a big flaw to me. Should I just ignore focus and use click?

Comment: @Fin you can do that but then it won't trigger when user is using keyboard only. Your choice, let me know your decision and I can add that timer stuff into my post.

Comment: yeah, the keyboard thing is important. I'm going to have to do both.